# RFID and Keypad Based Door Lock Using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I'm new to the Arduino world and I have a question. I found this project to do but I need your help, I want instead of this servomotor to put an electromagnetic door lock, could you help me with the changes in the scheme and code to understand this process? Thank you very much! I leave the diagram and the code here.

[image]

```
#include <deprecated.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <MFRC522Extended.h>
#include <require_cpp11.h>



// Include required libraries
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SPI.h>
// Create instances
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
MFRC522 mfrc522(10, 9); // MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN)
Servo sg90;
// Initialize Pins for led's, servo and buzzer
// Blue LED is connected to 5V
constexpr uint8_t greenLed = 7;
constexpr uint8_t redLed = 6;
constexpr uint8_t servoPin = 8;
constexpr uint8_t buzzerPin = 5;
char initial_password[4] = {'1', '2', '3', '4'};  // Variable to store initial password
String tagUID = "19 7F 30 C2";  // String to store UID of tag. Change it with your tag's UID
char password[4];   // Variable to store users password
boolean RFIDMode = true; // boolean to change modes
char key_pressed = 0; // Variable to store incoming keys
uint8_t i = 0;  // Variable used for counter
// defining how many rows and columns our keypad have
const byte rows = 4;
const byte columns = 4;
// Keypad pin map
char hexaKeys[rows][columns] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};
// Initializing pins for keypad
byte row_pins[rows] = {A0, A1, A2, A3};
byte column_pins[columns] = {2, 1, 0};
// Create instance for keypad
Keypad keypad_key = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), row_pins, column_pins, rows, columns);
void setup() {
  // Arduino Pin configuration
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  sg90.attach(servoPin);  //Declare pin 8 for servo
  sg90.write(0); // Set initial position at 90 degrees
  lcd.begin();   // LCD screen
  lcd.backlight();
  SPI.begin();      // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Init MFRC522
  lcd.clear(); // Clear LCD screen
}
void loop() {
  // System will first look for mode
  if (RFIDMode == true) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("   Door Lock");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(" Scan Your Tag ");
    // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
      return;
    }
    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
      return;
    }
    //Reading from the card
    String tag = "";
    for (byte j = 0; j < mfrc522.uid.size; j++)
    {
      tag.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[j] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
      tag.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[j], HEX));
    }
    tag.toUpperCase();
    //Checking the card
    if (tag.substring(1) == tagUID)
    {
      // If UID of tag is matched.
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Tag Matched");
      digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
      delay(3000);
      digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Enter Password:");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      RFIDMode = false; // Make RFID mode false
    }
    else
    {
      // If UID of tag is not matched.
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Wrong Tag Shown");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Access Denied");
      digitalWrite(buzzerPin, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
      delay(3000);
      digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
      lcd.clear();
    }
  }
  // If RFID mode is false, it will look for keys from keypad
  if (RFIDMode == false) {
    key_pressed = keypad_key.getKey(); // Storing keys
    if (key_pressed)
    {
      password[i++] = key_pressed; // Storing in password variable
      lcd.print("*");
    }
    if (i == 4) // If 4 keys are completed
    {
      delay(200);
      if (!(strncmp(password, initial_password, 4))) // If password is matched
      {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Pass Accepted");
        sg90.write(90); // Door Opened
        digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
        delay(3000);
        digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
        sg90.write(0); // Door Closed
        lcd.clear();
        i = 0;
        RFIDMode = true; // Make RFID mode true
      }
      else    // If password is not matched
      {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Wrong Password");
        digitalWrite(buzzerPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
        delay(3000);
        digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW);
        digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
        lcd.clear();
        i = 0;
        RFIDMode = true;  // Make RFID mode true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First: Please tell us, what electromagnetic doorlock you exactly have. A link to the product would be fine. Second: What exactly don't you understand in that code? Even without understanding the whole code you might get good results when playing with it a bit. The servo part is everything with `sg90`. You can then replace these parts with your door lock code.